# Dereference member pointer before operator[]

Tags: c++, stdvector, dereference

I can't seem to manage the syntax to access the elements of a vector, the pointer of which is contained in a structure. More after the MWE:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct vectag
  {
    std::vector<float> *X;
  } vec;

int main ()
  {
    vec A;
    A.X = new std::vector<float>(0);

    A.X->push_back(5.0);

    // This next line is the problem:
    float C = A.X[0];

    printf("%f\n", C);
    return 1;
  }
```

GCC (G++) says

```
14:24: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<float>’ to ‘float’ in initialization
```

and of course, it's quite right. In the line `float C = A.X[0];`, B.X[0] would be correct IF X was not a pointer (recall, `std::vector<float> *X;`).
What is the proper syntax for dereferencing X before operator[], so that I can access the elements of X?

P.S.
I am aware of the member function `at()`, and it is not an option *for me* because I don't want the overhead of range checking. This is part of a performance critical code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A.X[0]` attempts to access the first vector pointed to by `X` - which, remember, is a pointer.

To use `operator[]` on the vector itself, you can use `A.X->operator[](0)`, although quite honestly I don't see the reason why your member is a pointer and not an object.

Your code exibits undefined behavior, because `X` is an unitialized pointer

```
vec A;
A.X->push_back(5.0);
```

here.

Comment: A.X->operator[](0), works. Thanks. It is a pointer because in my application, it is packed in a struct with other things. The point of using the vect is that it is variable size, so I can't have it in the middle of a struct. Oh, and I just forgot to initialize it in the MWE. In my code, I do properly initialize it. I edited the MWE above.

Answer (score 5):

`A.X` is the pointer. You need to dereference it to access the vector that it points to:

```
float C = (*A.X)[0];
```

But if you haven't initialized `A.X` to point to anything, dereferencing it has Undefined Behavior, which it looks like you have in this program.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the line to initialize, but it was just an omission in the MWE. The problem remains. The modification you provided gives the error `no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘** A.vectag::X’`